# Converting Eigen 4x4 Matrix to QMatrix4x4

Tags: c++, arm, qt4, eigen

I've been converting RGBDSLAM to armhf (https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2) and I've been encountering errors with this function:

```
template <typename T >
QMatrix4x4 eigenTF2QMatrix(const T& transf)
{
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, Eigen::RowMajor> m = transf.matrix();
  //QMatrix4x4 qmat( static_cast<qreal*>( m.data() )  ); (original line)
  QMatrix4x4 qmat( m.data() );
  printQMatrix4x4("From Eigen::Transform", qmat);
  return qmat;
}
```

The line:

```
QMatrix4x4 qmat( m.data() );
```

as well as the original:

```
QMatrix4x4 qmat( static_cast<qreal*>( m.data() )  );
```

Gives me the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4, 1> >::Scalar* {aka double*}' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

How can I fix this function to work on arm?

Comment: Well, that's presumably why the cast was there originally - what was the issue with that?

Comment: qreal is a float instead of double on ARM. It didn't work.

Comment: You can hack `Qt` and change `qreal==float` and rebuild `Qt`, but little simpler to write cycle to copy each member of matrix.

Comment: Well that took so much longer than expected, but it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a pointer and expect it to work.  There is the `cast` method of Eigen, but it does not work with temporaries, so you will have to perform a copy:

```
using Eigen;
Matrix<qreal, 4, 4, RowMajor> mcopy = m.cast<qreal>();

QMatrix4x4 qmat(mcopy.data());
```